# Vite production build passes the wrong path to React lazy load

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a Django+React webpage that I have running successfully in production. None of the functionality seems to be broken, but I'm getting the following error in the console on visiting some of the pages:

```
Loading module from “https://example.com/assets/index-22312268.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading module from “https://example.com/assets/ChatPage-0969fc47.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

Because of the hosting for the Django app, the frontend files are all hosted under `/static/`. That link should go to `example.com/static/assets/ChatPage-0969fc47.js`, but the /static/ is missing. The MIME type error is because the link is incorrect, and is therefore loading a 404 page rather than the intended js. I am using React Router DOM v6, and it appears that the compiled lazy loading instructions are the problem. The output for the lazy load is here:

```js
Xs=Qe.lazy(()=>Oi(()=>import("./ChatPage-0969fc47.js"),["assets/ChatPage-0969fc47.js","assets/index-22312268.js"]))
```

The actual import() seems to be working because the site works as expected even in a private browser window, it just throws these unwanted error messages. The ["assets/..."] section seems to be the source of the errors.

I am using Vite, and the `vite.config.js` looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {manifest: true},
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/static/' : '/',
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

As I said, the site appears to work correctly, except for throwing these error messages. The generated `index.html` properly links to the `/static/assets/index-01abcdef.js` and `/static/assets/index-1a2b3c4d.css`, so Vite knows where things should be at least some of the time.

How do I stop these errors from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be with with the `base:` line in the vite config. Because I was building in a dev environment, the `/static/` was never used as the base. I replaced that section of the vite.config.js file with the following snippet, which uses the command issued (e.g., `npm run build`) to detect when it should be building for production. That has eliminated the errors.

```js
export default defineConfig(({ command }) => ({
  base: command === "build" ? "/static/" : "/",
  build: {
    manifest: true,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
}));
```